# Logout issue in Zend and jQuery Mobile

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-mobile

I am using Zend framework version 1.11.3 and jQuery mobile version 1.3.0 beta. On clicking the log out button I am redirected to the main page. The page does not get refreshed and the images are not loaded. However when I refresh the page the images get loaded. Here is my log out code ::Controller:

```
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->clearIdentity();
    $user_sessions = new Zend_Session_Namespace('user_sessions');
    $user_sessions->user_register_id="";
    $user_sessions->user_fname="";
    $user_sessions->user_username="";
    unset($user_sessions);
    return $this->_redirect('/index');
```

View:

```
      <span class="ui-btn-right"  >Welcome <a href="/profile" title="profile" style="color:white;">' . $name . '</a><a href="/logout">Logout</a>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: copy paste the image src attribute for both the cases.

Comment: Now, the images are loaded properly of the main page but login feature   is not working.When I refresh the page it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my view as follows and found it working.

```
     <span class="ui-btn-right"  >Welcome <a href="/profile" title="profile" style="color:white;">' . $name . '</a><div id="logout">Logout</div></span>
```

and added script

```
   <script>
     $( "#logout" ).on( "click", function() {
       document.location.href="/logout";

     });
   </script>
```